# How can you filter a field that has multiple values in a single cell?

Tags: looker-studio

I am building a dashboard in Google Data Studio. I have fields in my data set that contain multiple values in a single cell (*test*, *test2*, *test3*). I need to filter my metrics (fields) based on a defined values and provide a count. So, I would have a column for *test*, *test2* and *test3*, and below each would be a count for each of the matching dimensions.

I've tried a few things. I was thinking that using `CONTAINS_TEXT` might work, but that returns a `Boolean` value which I am not sure how to build a count off of. I've also tried using a couple of the RegEx functions with no luck. I do get data back, but typically it's a count of all the rows that contain any kind of text and not the specific text I am looking for.

Let's get a little more specific. I have a list of titles.

- CEO
- VP
- Manager
- ETC

In the DB that list has its own column called *Title*.
Now, I also have a column for Organization Type with value such as:

- Corporation
- Franchise
- Non-Profit
- ETC

What I want to be able to do is to create a chart that has the *Titles* listed as the dimension and then columns (metrics) for *Corporation*, *Franchise*, *Non-Profit*, *ETC*. Each would have a count of how many of that particular title are in each of those Organization Types. Each column would need to be filtered for a specific Organization Type. At least that is how I am going about thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be on the right lines with your contains_text() approach with something like:

```
SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(YourDimension, "Required Text") then YourMetric Else 0 end)
```